# WordPress Customizer Control with React

Tags: theme-development, javascript, theme-customizer

I am just doing a demo on the WordPress customizer API to edit the header with custom controls.

I have designed a custom control by extending WP_Customize_Control and Jquery to refresh/postMessage the element to speed up the UI experience, which is working fine.

But, When I compared this with react based Customizer which is much faster than PHP/JQuery based.

Is there any other ways/approaches to make customizer UI more faster?

Is there any starter example/doc to start working with React-based customizer controls etc?